# How to get repeated main key in groupby?

Tags: python, pandas

Whenever I use groupby i get results like:

```
 df.groupby(by =['day','gender']).['total].sum()
```

output:

```
gender day  sum
male   mon   56
       tues  45
       ..
female mon    44
       tues   25
        ...
```

output i want:

```
gender day  sum
male   mon   56
male   tues  45
       ..
female mon    44
female tues   25
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
df.groupby(by=['day', 'gender'], as_index=False).['total'].sum()
```